# Tag Filter display is off when viewing multiple, long tags

Tags: bug, tags, user-interface, filtering

I have a [saved filter with multiple, long tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/intersystems%20intersystems-cache%20intersystems-ensemble%20intersystems-cache-studio%20intersystems-cache-zen%20objectscript?mode=any).  When viewing the tab the tag field is a bit off.

[image]

Here is the rendered code:

[image]

And the selected element:

[image]

Chrome Version 47.0.2526.106 m (64-bit)